# Bitcoin core shutdown after running for about 1 day

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have my bitcoin core daemon up and running on Ubuntu. However it always stops after running for serveral hours or 1 day. Here's the debug.log before it stopped.

```
2023-11-23T18:04:42Z [net] Saw new cmpctblock header hash=000000000000000000019f034b4fed9b31aa4b5aad47c70cee86d784b5932216 peer=227
2023-11-23T18:04:43Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000019f034b4fed9b31aa4b5aad47c70cee86d784b5932216 height=818134 version=0x21dcc000 log2_work=94.557484 tx=924729575 date='2023-11-23T18:04:24Z' progress=1.000000 cache=109.0MiB(751559txo)
2023-11-23T18:15:43Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=818134, peer=720 (block-relay-only)
2023-11-23T18:18:12Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=818134, peer=725 (block-relay-only)
2023-11-23T18:33:21Z Saw new header hash=00000000000000000000cc3699401d8fe6893369744fc8fcbc1913032e67242a height=818135
2023-11-23T18:33:21Z [net] Saw new cmpctblock header hash=00000000000000000000cc3699401d8fe6893369744fc8fcbc1913032e67242a peer=5
2023-11-23T18:33:22Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000000cc3699401d8fe6893369744fc8fcbc1913032e67242a height=818135 version=0x20c00000 log2_work=94.557497 tx=924733362 date='2023-11-23T18:33:12Z' progress=1.000000 cache=109.6MiB(755110txo)
2023-11-23T18:33:22Z BlockUntilSyncedToCurrentChain: txindex is catching up on block notifications
2023-11-23T18:36:45Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=818135, peer=763 (block-relay-only)
2023-11-23T18:43:31Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=818135, peer=779 (block-relay-only)
2023-11-23T18:46:38Z Flushed fee estimates to fee_estimates.dat.
2023-11-23T18:48:57Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=818135, peer=791 (block-relay-only)
2023-11-23T18:49:35Z tor: Thread interrupt
2023-11-23T18:49:35Z Shutdown: In progress...
2023-11-23T18:49:35Z torcontrol thread exit
2023-11-23T18:49:35Z opencon thread exit
2023-11-23T18:49:35Z addcon thread exit
2023-11-23T18:49:35Z msghand thread exit
2023-11-23T18:49:35Z net thread exit
2023-11-23T18:49:35Z DumpAnchors: Flush 2 outbound block-relay-only peer addresses to anchors.dat started
2023-11-23T18:49:35Z DumpAnchors: Flush 2 outbound block-relay-only peer addresses to anchors.dat completed (0.01s)
2023-11-23T18:49:35Z scheduler thread exit
2023-11-23T18:49:36Z Writing 0 unbroadcast transactions to disk.
2023-11-23T18:49:36Z Dumped mempool: 0.27696s to copy, 0.66744s to dump
2023-11-23T18:49:37Z Flushed fee estimates to fee_estimates.dat.
2023-11-23T18:49:40Z Shutdown: done
```

I see it shutting down correctly, but I didn't do anything to interrupt or stop the process.

I start the daemon with: `nohup bitcoin-core.daemon &`

Is there anything I can do to this?

Thanks a lot!